# Animal perception of animal vs. inanimate objects

Tags: animal-cognition

I've always been baffled by the fact that safari vehicles are open to the elements. There are plenty of examples of lions approaching the cars and yet [barely noticing](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/qldwgqMViy0) the potential human preys seated on board. One explanation that circulates about this is that the felines recognize an inanimate object (the car) and thus "infers" that the rest of vehicle, including its passengers, is also inanimate.

I have a hard time buying this. Consider for example this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTg_llZyiow) of a lion who recognizes a human prey through the window grid of some house.

Note: Although most questions here are about human psychology, I'm tagging this question with `animal-cognition` for lack of a better classification.